# Using masm to displays the letter that counting in an input string

Tags: assembly, masm, counting

Using masm(Visual Studio 2010), write a program that inputs an entire line of text, up to 132 characters, into a buffer. Then have my program determine how many times each letter of the alphabet occurs. You are to count all letter a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 only. The screen should be out put a - 4 times, b - 2 times, c- 9 times.

Comment: Ok, here it is, edited answer : open Visual Studio 2010, create a new C++ console project, copy-paste my code and run it! (I wish I could post the entire project as RAR, gimme and email and I will send it to you).

Comment: my email is vuanhtuan15122005@yahoo.com....I did the same as you said but it the program still failed. Thank you for your help. http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/... I used Masm in Visual Studio 2010 and this link is one I learn to write assembly on it.

Comment: What do you mean "still failed"? It works like magic! In order to help you, I added only one line of code to my answer, go to the end, just before "return 0;", I added another "scanf" to stop the program so the screen doesn't disappear and you can see al the letters, digits and their counters. Add the same line to the project that I JUST SENT TO YOU BY EMAIL. Please, tell me it finally worked.

Comment: I saw the error "this line has error A3201". Just move "charInput[counter]" to a register (like EDX) under L3, then use the register instead : "cmp charInput[counter - 1] , EDX".

Answer (score 1):

I made your program with compiler EMU8086 Intel syntax (just copy-paste-run). It's big but fully commented to help you understand, this is what it does: display a message for user, capture a string from keyboard (max 132), count digits and letters (other are ignored), display counters. Here it is (more explanations after the code):

```
.stack 100h
.data

msj1      db 'Enter a line of text (132 max) : $'
text      db 133  ;MAX LENGTH 132, PLUS 1 FOR ENDING CHR(13).
          db ?    ;LENGTH ENTERED BY USER.
          db 133 dup(?)  ;THE STRING.

digits    dw 10 dup(0) ;ARRAY OF 10 COUNTERS FOR DIGITS.
uppercase dw 26 dup(0) ;ARRAY OF 26 COUNTERS FOR UPPERCASE LETTERS.
lowercase dw 26 dup(0) ;ARRAY OF 26 COUNTERS FOR LOWERCASE LETTERS.

str       db 6 dup('$') ;TO STORE NUMBER CONVERTED TO STRING. 
char      db ' =$' 
space     db '  $' 

.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

;DISPLAY MESSAGE TO CAPTURE LINE OF TEXT.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj1
  int  21h

;CAPTURE LINE OF TEXT.  
  mov  ah, 0AH
  mov  dx, offset text
  int  21h

;COUNT CHARACTERS OF THE LINE OF TEXT.
  mov  si, offset text + 2  ;SI POINTS TO BEGINNING OF STRING. THE FIRST 
                            ;2 BYTES ARE FOR CONTROL (MAX LENGTH, LENGTH).
repeat:
;CHECK IF CURRENT CHARACTER IS DIGIT, UPPERCASE OR LOWERCASE.
  mov  bl, [ si ]  ;GET CURRENT CHARACTER.
  call check_digit
  call check_uppercase
  call check_lowercase
;NEXT CHARACTER.
  inc  si
  mov  bl, [ si ]
  cmp  bl, 13
  jne  repeat ;IF NEXT CHARACTER IS NOT 13, REPEAT.

;DISPLAY COUNTERS.
  call clear_screen
  call display_digit_counters    
  call display_uppercase_counters    
  call display_lowercase_counters    

;WAIT FOR A KEY.
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h                   

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 10 COUNTERS OF THE
;ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR DIGITS.

proc display_digit_counters  
  mov  di, offset digits  ;DI POINTS TO ARRAY.
  mov  bp, 10  ;ARRAY LENGTH.
display_digits:
;DISPLAY SPACE.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset space
  int  21h
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN STRING.
  call dollars
  mov  ax, [ di ]
  call number2string  ;STRING RETURNS IN VARIABLE "STR".
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN CORRESPONDING DIGIT. FOR
;EXAMPLE, IF CURRENT COUNTER IS 3, CONVERT 3 IN '3'.
  mov  ax, di            ;GET CURRENT COUNTER OFFSET.
  sub  ax, offset digits ;CONVERT TO 0..9.
  shr  ax, 1             ;DIVIDE OFFSET BECAUSE COUNTERS ARE DW.
  add  al, 48            ;CONVERT TO '0'..'9'.
  mov  char, al          ;STORE DIGIT IN STRING TO DISPLAY.
;DISPLAY DIGIT FOR CURRENT COUNTER BELONGS TO.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset char
  int  21h
;DISPLAY CURRENT COUNTER.         
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  add  di, 2  ;EVERY COUNTER IS DW (TWO BYTES).
  dec  bp
  jnz  display_digits  ;IF ( BP > 0 ) JUMP.

  ret
endp    

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 26 COUNTERS OF THE
;ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR UPPERCASE LETTERS.

proc display_uppercase_counters  
  mov  di, offset uppercase  ;DI POINTS TO ARRAY.
  mov  bp, 26  ;ARRAY LENGTH.
display_uppercase:
;DISPLAY SPACE.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset space
  int  21h
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN STRING.
  call dollars
  mov  ax, [ di ]
  call number2string  ;STRING RETURNS IN VARIABLE "STR".
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN CORRESPONDING LETTER. FOR
;EXAMPLE, IF CURRENT COUNTER IS 3, CONVERT 3 IN 'D'.
  mov  ax, di            ;GET CURRENT COUNTER OFFSET.
  sub  ax, offset uppercase ;CONVERT TO 0..25.
  shr  ax, 1             ;DIVIDE OFFSET BECAUSE COUNTERS ARE DW.
  add  al, 65            ;CONVERT TO 'A'..'Z'.
  mov  char, al          ;STORE LETTER IN STRING TO DISPLAY.
;DISPLAY LETTER FOR CURRENT COUNTER BELONGS TO.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset char
  int  21h
;DISPLAY CURRENT COUNTER.         
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  add  di, 2  ;EVERY COUNTER IS DW (TWO BYTES).
  dec  bp
  jnz  display_uppercase  ;IF ( BP > 0 ) JUMP.

  ret
endp    

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 26 COUNTERS OF THE
;ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR LOWERCASE LETTERS.

proc display_lowercase_counters  
  mov  di, offset lowercase  ;DI POINTS TO ARRAY.
  mov  bp, 26  ;ARRAY LENGTH.
display_lowercase:
;DISPLAY SPACE.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset space
  int  21h
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN STRING.
  call dollars
  mov  ax, [ di ]
  call number2string  ;STRING RETURNS IN VARIABLE "STR".
;CONVERT CURRENT COUNTER IN CORRESPONDING LETTER. FOR
;EXAMPLE, IF CURRENT COUNTER IS 3, CONVERT 3 IN 'd'.
  mov  ax, di            ;GET CURRENT COUNTER OFFSET.
  sub  ax, offset lowercase ;CONVERT TO 0..25.
  shr  ax, 1             ;DIVIDE OFFSET BECAUSE COUNTERS ARE DW.
  add  al, 97            ;CONVERT TO 'a'..'z'.
  mov  char, al          ;STORE LETTER IN STRING TO DISPLAY.
;DISPLAY LETTER FOR CURRENT COUNTER BELONGS TO.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset char
  int  21h
;DISPLAY CURRENT COUNTER.         
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  add  di, 2  ;EVERY COUNTER IS DW (TWO BYTES).
  dec  bp
  jnz  display_lowercase  ;IF ( BP > 0 ) JUMP.

  ret
endp    

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL
;IS A DIGIT ('0'..'9'). IF IT IS, INCREASES
;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "DIGITS".

proc check_digit        
  cmp  bl, '0'
  jb   not_a_digit  ;IF AL < '0' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, '9'
  ja   not_a_digit  ;IF AL > '9' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS A DIGIT. INCREASE COUNTER USING
;THE DIGIT AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR DIGIT '3' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 48  ;CONVERT DIGIT IN NUMBER ('0'..'9'->0..9).
  mov  bh, 0  ;CLEAR BH TO USE BX.                       
  shl  bx, 1  ;MULTIPLY BY 2 BECASE EVERY COUNTER IS DW (2 BYTES).
  add  bx, offset digits  ;BX POINTS TO THE APPROPIATE COUNTER.
  inc  [ bx ]  ;INCREASE COUNTER OF DIGIT.

not_a_digit:
  ret
endp

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL IS
;AN UPPERCASE LETTER ('A'..'Z'). IF IT IS, INCREASE
;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "UPPERCASE'.

proc check_uppercase
  cmp  bl, 'A'
  jb   not_uppercase  ;IF AL < 'A' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, 'Z'
  ja   not_uppercase  ;IF AL > 'Z' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS AN UPPERCASE LETTER. INCREASE COUNTER
;USING THE LETTER AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR LETTER 'C' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 65  ;CONVERT DIGIT IN NUMBER ('A'..'Z'->0..25).
  mov  bh, 0  ;CLEAR BH TO USE BX.
  shl  bx, 1  ;MULTIPLY BY 2 BECASE EVERY COUNTER IS DW (2 BYTES).
  add  bx, offset uppercase  ;BX POINTS TO THE APPROPIATE COUNTER.
  inc  [ bx ]  ;INCREASE COUNTER OF UPPERCASE LETTER.

not_uppercase:
  ret
endp

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL IS
;A LOWERCASE LETTER ('a'..'z'). IF IT IS, INCREASE
;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "LOWERCASE".

proc check_lowercase
  cmp  bl, 'a'
  jb   not_lowercase  ;IF AL < 'a' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, 'z'
  ja   not_lowercase  ;IF AL > 'z' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS A LOWERCASE LETTER. INCREASE COUNTER
;USING THE LETTER AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR LETTER 'c' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 97  ;CONVERT LETTER IN NUMBER ('a'..'z'->0..25).
  mov  bh, 0  ;CLEAR BH TO USE BX.
  shl  bx, 1  ;MULTIPLY BY 2 BECASE EVERY COUNTER IS DW (2 BYTES).
  add  bx, offset lowercase  ;BX POINTS TO THE APPROPIATE COUNTER.
  inc  [ bx ]  ;INCREASE COUNTER OF LOWERCASE LETTER.

not_lowercase:
  ret
endp

;------------------------------------------
;NUMBER TO CONVERT MUST ENTER IN AX.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING.

proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  mov  si, offset str
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp  

;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE STR WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THESE STRINGS WILL BE DISPLAYED.
proc dollars                 
  mov  si, offset str
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  al, '$'
  mov  [ si ], al
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars
  ret
endp  

;------------------------------------------
proc clear_screen
  mov  ah,0
  mov  al,3
  int  10H
  ret
endp
```

In data segment you'll find three arrays : digits, lowercase and uppercase. These are the counters. The idea is to use the same characters as offset inside the array. For example, the first position of array digits is the counter for digit 0. The first position of array lowercase is the counter for 'a'.

The code is structured in procedures, some of them are very alike: check_digit (check_lowercase, check_uppercase), display_digit_counters (display_lowercase_counters, display_uppercase_counters).

**Now the same program for Visual Studio 2010 C++ console project. Next code must be copy-pasted in the code file that contains the main method ("int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[ ]") :**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char msj1[50];
char text[135];
int arr_digits[ 10 ];
int arr_lowercase[ 26 ];
int arr_uppercase[ 26 ];
char str[6];
char charr;
char char_equal;
char space[4];
int idx,i,tmp;

void printspace () {
printf( space );
}
void printstr () {
printf( str );
}
void print_char_equal () {
printf( "%c",char_equal );
}
void print_digit_counter () {
printf( "%d",arr_digits[ i ] );
}   
// THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 10 COUNTERS OF THE
// ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR DIGITS.
void printcharr_digit () {
printf( "%c",i+48 );
}
void display_digit_counters () {
__asm {
  mov  i, 0
display_digits:
  call printspace
  call printcharr_digit
  call print_char_equal
  call print_digit_counter
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  inc  i
  cmp  i, 10
  jne  display_digits  ;IF ( I != 10 ) JUMP.
}
}
//;THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 26 COUNTERS OF THE
//;ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR UPPERCASE LETTERS.
void printcharr_uppercase () {
printf( "%c",i+65 );
}
void print_uppercase_counter () {
printf( "%d",arr_uppercase[ i ] );
}   

void display_uppercase_counters () {
__asm {
  mov  i, 0
display_uppercase:
  call printspace
  call printcharr_uppercase
  call print_char_equal
  call print_uppercase_counter
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  inc  i
  cmp  i, 26
  jne  display_uppercase  ;IF ( I != 26 ) JUMP.
}
}
//;THIS PROCEDURE DISPLAYS THE 26 COUNTERS OF THE
//;ARRAY OF COUNTERS FOR LOWERCASE LETTERS.
void printcharr_lowercase () {
printf( "%c",i+97 );
}
void print_lowercase_counter () {
printf( "%d",arr_lowercase[ i ] );
}   

void display_lowercase_counters () {
__asm {
  mov  i, 0
display_lowercase:
  call printspace
  call printcharr_lowercase
  call print_char_equal
  call print_lowercase_counter
;NEXT COUNTER TO DISPLAY.
  inc  i
  cmp  i, 26
  jne  display_lowercase  ;IF ( I != 10 ) JUMP.
}
}
//;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL
//;IS A DIGIT ('0'..'9'). IF IT IS, INCREASES
//;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "DIGITS".
void inc_digit () {
arr_digits[ idx ]++;
}

void check_digit () {
__asm {
  and  ebx, 0ffh
  cmp  bl, '0'
  jb   not_a_digit  ;IF AL < '0' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, '9'
  ja   not_a_digit  ;IF AL > '9' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS A DIGIT. INCREASE COUNTER USING
;THE DIGIT AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR DIGIT '3' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 48  ;CONVERT DIGIT IN NUMBER ('0'..'9'->0..9).
  mov  idx, ebx
  call inc_digit

not_a_digit:
}
}
//;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL IS
//;AN UPPERCASE LETTER ('A'..'Z'). IF IT IS, INCREASE
//;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "UPPERCASE'.
void inc_uppercase () {
arr_uppercase[ idx ]++;
}

void check_uppercase () {
__asm {
  and  ebx, 0ffh
  cmp  bl, 'A'
  jb   not_uppercase  ;IF AL < 'A' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, 'Z'
  ja   not_uppercase  ;IF AL > 'Z' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS AN UPPERCASE LETTER. INCREASE COUNTER
;USING THE LETTER AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR LETTER 'C' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 65  ;CONVERT DIGIT IN NUMBER ('A'..'Z'->0..25).
  mov  idx, ebx
  call inc_uppercase

not_uppercase:
}
}
//;THIS PROCEDURE CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IN BL IS
//;A LOWERCASE LETTER ('a'..'z'). IF IT IS, INCREASE
//;THE APPROPIATE COUNTER IN ARRAY "LOWERCASE".
void inc_lowercase () {
arr_lowercase[ idx ]++;
}
void check_lowercase  () {
__asm {
  and  ebx, 0ffh
  cmp  bl, 'a'
  jb   not_lowercase  ;IF AL < 'a' FINISH.
  cmp  bl, 'z'
  ja   not_lowercase  ;IF AL > 'z' FINISH.
;IF NO JUMP, AL IS A LOWERCASE LETTER. INCREASE COUNTER
;USING THE LETTER AS OFFSET INSIDE THE ARRAY OF COUNTERS,
;FOR EXAMPLE, THE COUNTER FOR LETTER 'c' IS THE THIRD
;POSITION IN THE ARRAY.
  sub  bl, 97  ;CONVERT LETTER IN NUMBER ('a'..'z'->0..25).
  mov  idx, ebx
  call inc_lowercase
not_lowercase:
}
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
strcpy( msj1,"Enter a line of text (132 max) : " );
char_equal = '=';
strcpy( space,"  " );

printf( msj1 );
scanf( "%s",text );
__asm {

;COUNT CHARACTERS OF THE LINE OF TEXT.
  lea  esi, text  ;SI POINTS TO BEGINNING OF STRING. THE FIRST 
                 ;2 BYTES ARE FOR CONTROL (MAX LENGTH, LENGTH).
repeat:
;CHECK IF CURRENT CHARACTER IS DIGIT, UPPERCASE OR LOWERCASE.
  mov  tmp, esi
  mov  bl, [ esi ]  ;GET CURRENT CHARACTER.
  call check_digit  
  mov  esi, tmp
  mov  bl, [ esi ]  ;GET CURRENT CHARACTER.
  call check_uppercase
  mov  esi, tmp
  mov  bl, [ esi ]  ;GET CURRENT CHARACTER.
  call check_lowercase
  mov  esi, tmp
;NEXT CHARACTER.
  inc  esi
  mov  bl, [ esi ]
  cmp  bl, 0
  jne  repeat ;IF NEXT CHARACTER IS NOT 13, REPEAT.

;DISPLAY COUNTERS.
  call display_digit_counters    
  call display_uppercase_counters    
  call display_lowercase_counters    
}
scanf( "%s",text );
return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't allow to use interrupts (like int 21h or int 10h), so, printf and scanf are used instead. Important : notice the procedures respect the "top-down" style, where procedures must be declared before (above) they are called.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am using visual studio 2010 so it is a lot of different syntax that I still try to figure out with your code. I got the idea. thanks

Comment: Try adding an ASM file to your project and paste my code on it, like this = https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/vsasm.html , then just make some little changes, like PROC and ENDP after the proc name. Let me if it worked for you.

Comment: str       BYTE 6 DUP('$')-> this line has syntax error: DUP(error A2008). Yes I am changing the PROC and ENDP but it is still a lot of different syntax need to debug in Visual studio 2010. Thank for the link. I knew how to create a new project:)