# I am trying to copy an variables into an array

Tags: assembly

I am trying to copy variables and paste it to my array. The way I am trying to do is following but my emulator is giving me an error saying wrong parameters. How can I do that. Assuming that there are values already in `count_a` and `count_b`

```
.model

.data

frequency dw dup(0)

count_a   dw ?

count_b   dw ? 

.code

mov bx,[frequency]     ;Effective Address of Frequency in bx

   mov [bx],count_a

   add bx,2

   mov [bx],count_b

end
```

Comment: Just for fun, I almost finish the Huffman program. I will append it to my answer to your question about Huffman algorithm as soon as I finish it. But I can see you are working hard on it (keep going!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy memory to memory (one variable to another variable), you will have to use a register in the middle, like this:

```
.model

.data

frequency dw dup(0)

count_a   dw ?

count_b   dw ? 

.code

   mov bx,[frequency]     ;Effective Address of Frequency in bx

   MOV DX,count_a
   mov [bx],DX

   add bx,2

   MOV DX,count_b
   mov [bx],DX

end
```

It's not allowed to move data from count_a to [bx], so we can use DX (or any other register) to store the value and pass it from one memory location to the other.

By the way, "mov bx,[frequency]" is not the effective address of frequency, this is:

```
lea bx, frequency
```

Now BX contains the effective address of frequency, thanks to "lea" instruction. Another way:

```
mov bx, offset frequency
```

What you were doing with "mov bx,[frequency]" was transfering the first two bytes of the array frequency to bx.

One last comment: "frequency" doesn't look like an array, it should be:

```
frequency dw 256 dup(0)
```

Comment: Because when I wanted to see the display that what is stored in that I showed me nothing

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. Maybe my codes for displaying of array which should not be

Comment: If you are storing numbers, you will have to convert them to string to display them. Use my method number2string here = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761714/using-masm-to-displays-the-letter-that-counting-in-an-input-string/29776675#29776675

Comment: What do you mean by converting to strings?

Comment: For example, if you display number 65 you will see 'A'. To display '65' you have to convert the number 65 into '6' and '5'.

Comment: Please, accept my answer again (I was so happy). You know how much time and effort I do for you and all you have to do is one little click on the check mark  (^_^).

Comment: Oh sure no problem. Sorry about that. That was just a mistake

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate for all the work you do for students. You are talented one

Comment: actually now it worked. I had to add 48 to it because it's following asci table. Thank you so much for you help